# show object template angular which counts the number of repeated words

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show the Object wordCounts,which stores a series of words with a value that is the number of times a word is repeated in a string, what happens is that I want to show that variable in order by the number of repetitions that word has, and I just want the 20 most repeated words to be shown. The main problem I have is that as far as I have the code it returns a JSON, which does not allow me to put in a div to give it a style.

**project-details.ts**

```
getWordCount(str) {
let arrayOfWords = str.split(/\s+/);

var wordCounts = Object.create(null);

for(let i = 0; i<arrayOfWords.length; i++){
  let word = arrayOfWords[i];

  if(!wordCounts[word]){
    wordCounts[word] = 1;
  }else{
    wordCounts[word] ++;
  }
}
    return wordCounts;  
};
```

**project-details.html**

```
 <p>{{getWordCount(str) | keyvalue | json}}</p>
```

**representation**

```
[ { "key": "También", "value": 1 }, { "key": "Un", "value": 1 }, { "key": "algoritmo", "value": 1 }, { "key": "aunque", "value": 1 }, { "key": "caracteres", "value": 1 }, { "key": "cifrado", "value": 1 }, { "key": "codificados", "value": 1 }, { "key": "composición", "value": 2 }, { "key": "cualquier", "value": 1 }, { "key": "de", "value": 5 }, { "key": "descifrado", "value": 1 }, { "key": "destinatario", "value": 1 }, { "key": "en", "value": 1 }, { "key": "es", "value": 2 }, { "key": "escritura", "value": 1 }, { "key": "forma", "value": 1 }, { "key": "generados", "value": 1 }, { "key": "imprimibles", "value": 1 }, { "key": "no", "value": 1 }, { "key": "original.", "value": 1 }, { "key": "para", "value": 1 }, { "key": "persona,", "value": 1 }, { "key": "por", "value": 2 }, { "key": "puede", "value": 1 }, { "key": "que", "value": 1 }, { "key": "que,", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sentido", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sentido.", "value": 1 }, { "key": "ser", "value": 1 }, { "key": "signos", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sistema", "value": 1 }, { "key": "su", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sí", "value": 1 }, { "key": "texto", "value": 1 }, { "key": "tienen", "value": 1 }, { "key": "un", "value": 2 }, { "key": "una", "value": 3 }, { "key": "unidad", "value": 1 } ]
```

And with that result I can't give it any style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the value to a variable, remove the `json` pipe and loop the value directly in the HTML. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class WordComponent {
  wordCount: any;

  getWordCount(str) {
    let arrayOfWords = str.split(/\s+/);
    let wordCounts = Object.create(null);

    for(let i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.length - 1; i++){
      let word = arrayOfWords[i];
      wordCounts[word] ? wordCounts[word]++ : wordCounts[word] = 1;
    }

    return wordCounts;  
  };

  onMouseUp(str: string) {
    this.wordCount = this.getWordCount(str);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<button (mouseup)="onMouseUp('str')">Get word count</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="wordCount">
  <p class="style" *ngFor="let word of wordCount | keyvalue">{{ word.key }} : {{ word.value }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

You can then modify and render as per you wish. Also note the loop condition should be `arrayOfWords.length - 1` because index starts from zero.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a `ShowWordCounts` component which takes your object as an `@Input` and generates the corresponding template.